# Как прикрепить архив к письму php mail()

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Пишу на процедурном php. Есть скрипт для генерации бэкапов сайта и создания архива с этими данными. Затем скрипт должен прикрепить этот файл к письму. Не понимаю, как это сделать с архивом.

```php
<?php


$backup_folder = '/home/t/tip***/backup';    // куда будут сохранятся файлы
$backup_name = '***_backup_' . date("d-m-Y");    // имя архива
$dir = '/home/t/tip***/';    // что бэкапим
$delay_delete = 30 * 24 * 3600;    // время жизни архива (в секундах)


$mail_to = '***@yandex.ru';
$mail_subject = '***-projects backup';
$mail_message = '';
$mail_headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$mail_headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

$mail_headers .= 'From: ***-projects.ru <whisper@***-projects.ru>' . "\r\n";

function backupFiles($backup_folder, $backup_name, $dir)
{
    $fullFileName = $backup_folder . '/' . $backup_name . '.tar.gz';
    shell_exec("tar -cvf " . $fullFileName . " " . $dir . "/* ");
    return $fullFileName;
}


function deleteOldArchives($backup_folder, $delay_delete)
{
    $this_time = time();
    $files = glob($backup_folder . "/*.tar.gz*");
    $deleted = array();
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if ($this_time - filemtime($file) > $delay_delete) {
            array_push($deleted, $file);
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
    return $deleted;
}



$start = microtime(true);    // запускаем таймер

$deleteOld = deleteOldArchives($backup_folder, $delay_delete);    // удаляем старые архивы
$doBackupFiles = backupFiles($backup_folder, $backup_name, $dir);    // делаем бэкап файлов

// добавляем в письмо отчеты
if ($doBackupFiles) {
    $mail_message .= 'site backuped successfully<br/>';
    $mail_message .= 'Files: ' . $doBackupFiles . '<br/>';
    
}


if ($deleteOld) {
    foreach ($deleteOld as $val) {
        $mail_message .= 'File deleted: ' . $val . '<br/>';
    }
}

$time = microtime(true) - $start;     // считаем время, потраченое на выполнение скрипта
$mail_message .= 'script time: ' . $time . '<br/>';
echo 'nice!';

mail($mail_to, $mail_subject, $mail_message, $mail_headers);    // и отправляем письмо

?>
```

Пути определяются верно, архив создается, как прикрепить архив к письму?

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275070/php-mail-attachment-problems

Comment: Я видел, немного не допер, как это можно использовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал функцию на основе https://stackoverflow.com/a/6275152/14196309, чтобы Вам было проще разобраться. Добавьте её в свой код, а те участки где формируются заголовки и происходит отправка письма через mail() - удалите.

```
function sendMailWithAttachment(
    string $fromName,
    string $fromMail,
    string $toMail,
    string $replyTo,
    string $subject,
    string $message,
    string $filePath
): void
{
    if (empty($filePath) || !file_exists($filePath)) {
        $errorMsg = sprintf(
            'Ошибка, не удалось найти файл для вложения. Путь: %s',
            $filePath
        );
        throw new Exception($errorMsg);
    }

    $eol = PHP_EOL;
    $uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
    $fileName = basename($filePath);

    $fileHandle = fopen($filePath, "r");
    $contents = fread($fileHandle, filesize($filePath));
    fclose($fileHandle);
    $contents = chunk_split(base64_encode($contents));

    $headers = "From: " . $fromName . ' <' . $fromMail . '>' . $eol;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $replyTo . $eol;
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . $eol;
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"";
    $headers .= $uid . "\"";

    $body = "--" . $uid . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . $eol . $eol;
    $body .= $message . $eol;

    $body .= "--" . $uid . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream;";
    $body .= " name=\"" . $fileName . "\"" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64" . $eol;
    $body .= "Content-Disposition: attachment" . $eol . $eol;
    $body .= $contents . $eol;
    $body .= "--" . $uid . "--";

    if (mail($toMail, $subject, $body, $headers) === false) {
        $errorMsg = sprintf(
            'Ошибка, не удалось отправить сообщение. Подробности: %s',
            error_get_last()['message'] ?? 'n\a'
        );
        throw new Exception($errorMsg);
    }
}
```

Пример использования, остается только подставить ваши переменные.

```
sendMailWithAttachment(
    'Имя Фамилия',
    'from@example.com',
    'to@example.com',
    'no-reply@example.com',
    'Тема письма',
    'Текст сообщения',
    __DIR__ . '/tmp/backup.tar.gz'
);
```